# How to add blackbars on image and must stay on image ratio

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

how to add the black bars on my div with 400x400 div size.

if the picture is portrait, it would add black bars on left and right,
and when the picture is widescreen the black bars will be added on top and bottom.

```
<div>
    <img src="image.png" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

I have no sleep for almost 2 days because of this.
I don't understand on this.

this is the sample picture:

[image]

please help me

**EDIT1:**

hello, can you check my html... it should be perfect align, but the picture have different size the alignment broken... look at this.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaorKq

**EDIT2**

It's already but when the width higher the image pass through
[image]
check here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVXMee

Comment: CSS cannot detect whether the image is portrait or landscape but you can JS to find(width and height), add a class to the image and then use CSS.

Comment: do you know how to fix it? just add blackbars to fit on the 400x400 div and not stretched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

I've made a pure CSS solution that should work up to IE8. :)
Also, it should work with any width/height.

```
.image-background {
  background: #000;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  position: relative;
}

.image-container {
  display: table-cell;  
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNZJwe

Good luck!

Comment: hello, can you check my html... it should be perfect align, but the picture have different size the alignment broken... look at this.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaorKq

Comment: You only needed to wrap all your img-container element inside another div, so the images will be aligned properly. See this updated codepen: http://codepen.io/Himechi90/pen/wKepzr

Comment: yeah it's working on other, but others that have high width will not work... like this sample.. http://i.imgur.com/PG1UYo6.png

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS,JS and HTML markup to achive this:

```
<style>
    .img-container {
        width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      background-color: black;
      position:relative;
    }
    .img-container img {   
      position:absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;      
    }    
  </style>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      debugger;
      var img = $('.img-container img');
      img.css('margin-top', - ($('.img-container img').height() / 2) +         'px');
      img.css('margin-left', - ($('.img-container img').width() / 2) + 'px');         
    });
  </script>

<div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" />   
</div>
```

Comment: hello.. what if my div isn't actually 400x400 cause it's actually depend on bootstrap responsive...

Answer (score 0):

Your div is 400*400, but your image is small, When you have used img-responsive that means img  `max-size : 100 %`. But here you want to see `min-size:100%`.

You can try below code

```
<img src="image.png" class="img-responsive  full-width" /> <!--add class full-width-->
```

in your css file

```
.full-width{
 width:100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stripped-down version of what @Himechi90 wrote.

If you only need one image instead of a row, basically all you need is:

```css
.image-full-view {
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-full-view img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-full-view">
  <img src="https://media.usfcvast.org/images/cvast-arches/projects/la_mancha/la_motilla_del_azuer/la_motilla_del_azuer_aerial.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object-fit: contain;`

css:

```
.image-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 16rem;
    background-color: black;
    width: auto;
}

.image-item {
    object-fit: contain;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="image-item" src="images/Screenshot(1).jpg">
</div>
```