# Fitting a 'widescreen' image into a square div

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding a instagram section into an Angular webapp. The problem is video thumbnails on Instagram are widescreen (rectangular), and photo thumbnails are square. Instead of getting a nice grid of squares, some are rectangles, ruining the design.

Is there anyway to automatically add black bars to the top and bottom of these widescreen images to make them squares? All thumbs should be need to be the same size. The solution does need to be dynamic/responsive, so I cannot use fixed widths and heights and then stretch the thumbs manually.

I am using bootstrap in order to organize/display the thumbnail grid.

I have already tried setting the square div's background images to the thumbnails to no avail. I have also tried setting the background color of the photo div in hopes of achieving a black bar effect. I would like to maintain the aspect ratio if possible hence the black bars

[Notice how the one thumb is a rectangle, and not square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFxIR.png)

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-4 ig-posts" *ngFor="let igPost of igPosts" (click)="gotoigPost(igPost)">
   <img [src]="igPost.imageUrl" class="img-fluid" id="ig-post" />
   </div>
</div>
```

```css
.ig-posts{
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2.5%;
    padding-bottom: 2.5%;  
}

#ig-post{
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008358/how-to-add-blackbars-on-image-and-must-stay-on-image-ratio) to no avail

Comment: do we only handle the width or also the height? because your wide pictures can also be tall like horizontal/vertical. I mean there are basically two scenarios in which the picture doesnt fit: too wide or too tall. Do you have both or just wide pictures?

Answer (score 2):

I think you search for `object-fit` or otherwise setting the image as `background`.

> The [object-fit](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) property defines how an element responds to the height and width of its content box. It's intended for images, videos and other embeddable media formats in conjunction with the object-position property. Used by itself, object-fit lets us crop an inline image by giving us fine-grained control over how it squishes and stretches inside its box.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by making three divs. A background div, a container div, and the actual image div. Using tables I was able to achieve the desired result. Thanks all!